# JS function using .text not replacing text exactly as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS/JQ function to toggle a user between following and unfollowing a question. In some places in my app users can click on a link with link text "Follow" or "Unfollow". In other places they can click on a button that is labelled "FOLLOW" or "UNFOLLOW". I was hoping my `this.text()` tests would only update the lowercase or uppercase label, depending on whether I'm calling my function from a link or a button. But it always seems to execute both tests. So if I click on a link with link text = "Follow" I end up with link text = "UNFOLLOW" when my function is done. Any suggestions?

```
$(function () {
    $(".question_follow_unfollow").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (IS_AUTHENTICATED == 'false') {
            window.location = '/login/?next=/';
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/question/follow-unfollow/",
                data: {
                    'qid': $(this).data('qid')
                },
                success: function (e) {
                    alert('Got it!');
                }
            });
            $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Follow' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow');
            $(this).text($(this).text() == 'FOLLOW' ? 'UNFOLLOW' : 'FOLLOW');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have areas where the text is all in uppercase, I would class this as a *style* and therefore this should be set with CSS:

```
.uppercase
{
   text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
$(this).text($(this).text() == 'Follow' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow');
```

Comment: That worked. And required the least amount of code change ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The following happens:

- text is `Follow` so it gets changed to `Unfollow`
- then the other line runs:
- `Unfollow` is not equal to `FOLLOW` so you get `UNFOLLOW`

You need more checks, or change it.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
var arr = {
    'Follow': 'Unfollow',
    'Unfollow': 'Follow',
    'UNFOLLOW': 'FOLLOW',
    'FOLLOW': 'UNFOLLOW'
}

$(this).text( arr[ $(this).text() ] );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you are not going to be able to use the ternary operator if it can be more than one case and you need to keep that case. Easiest thing is a switch

```
var theText = $(this).text();
var replacement = "";
switch (theText) {
    case : "UNFOLLOW" : replacement = "FOLLOW"; break;
    case : "unfollow" : replacement = "follow"; break;
    case : "FOLLOW" :  replacement = "UNFOLLOW"; break;
    case : "follow" :  replacement = "unfollow"; break;
}
$(this).text(replacement);
```